# Save Dynamic Tilemap Layer Locally

Tags: phaser-framework

I’m trying to make a game that has a map editor, and I would like to save layers locally to the file system. Can somebody help me to add this feature? And I also don’t have anything because I don’t know where to start, so I don’t have any code to show.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript/HTML5 you cannot save to a file without a user action. You can present the user with a save-file dialog and then save whatever data you have to a file, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file).

Alternatively, you can just save your layers objects to the local storage, which is storage within the browser cache. The only downside is that if you open the same page in a different browser (for example switch from FireFox to Chrome) then the save is not available. For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage).

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide custom code for your objects and your project, you'll have to create it yourself. But I will say that Javascript objects can easily be converted to plain-text strings using Javascript's built in `JSON.stringify(myobj)` function, you can save the text to file or localstorage. And then later you can read from a text and use `JSON.parse(mystr)` to convert it from string back to an object again.